# Laravel 5: return number of affected rows MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

how to return something similar to PHP function `mysql_affected_rows()` when use Laravel 5 DB class,

ex:
`DB::delete("DELETE FROM chat WHERE user_id = {$mid}");`

how to return number of affected rows?

thanks,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For `update()` and `delete()` calls, the return value is the number of affected rows.

```
$affected = DB::delete("DELETE FROM chat WHERE id = {$mid}");
```

Comment: What about insert calls?

Comment: A bool for success, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try?

> **[Official manual](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database)**: The delete method should be used to delete records from the database. Like update, the number of rows deleted will be returned:

`$deleted = DB::delete('delete from users');`

Answer (score 1):

You may get affected row by using Query builder

**For Laravel 5**

```
$ids=[10,20,30,40];

$updatedRow=DB::update('update test_table set status = 1 where id != ?', $ids);

echo $updatedRow;
exit;
```